# Customising Wordpress Template

Tags: wordpress, templates

I bought a Template Monster WP Template in order to customize it. I want it not to have any "blog" structuring. What I mean by that is losing the author name, comments closed notification, sidebar presence in various pages. Does anyone know where I can find tutorials on this or any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create child theme on top of Template Monster and override it
http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do -

Open all of the theme's files in notepad++ or another text editor.

Use Chrome's inspect element to select the author name and element.

Let's say it is - `<h1 class="author-title">Some Author</h1>`

I will then select `<h1 class="author-title">` and search all files for this in my text editor. My guess is that it will probably be in single.php

You can than delete or comment out the section and It will no longer appear on the page.